# upload via ftp downloadable products

Tags: downloadable

i need to upload the file of downloadable products via ftp because are video and are big, upper 2gb.
So in downloadable information i need to put the url of file but i try different test but somethings wrong, the link is always invalid.
Someone can explain me some solution of this problem?
If i put the file into directory /media/downloadable/files/ what is the exactly url i need to write in Products info.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select `URL` option for `Links` or `Samples` of Downloadable products you need to ensure that Magento can access the file via this URL. As customers won’t see the original URL and it will be fetched and delivered by Magento. So, if file placed into */media/downloadable/files/filename.jpg* and your store Base URL is *http://example.com/*, the file URL should be *http://example.com/media/downloadable/files/filename.jpg* and Magento should be able to get the file (make sure that `.htaccess` or server configuration does not block access, usually */media/downloadable/* is blocked by `.htaccess` to prevent unauthorized downloads).

There is a simpler option, though. You can upload a small file (may be even empty file) with required filename and extension into `Links` or `Sample` section and replace it via FTP with your real file. It will be saved under `/media/downloadable/files/[first_letter]/[second_letter]/filename.ext`. This option is faster as on delivery Magento can get the file directly from filesystem, not from URL.

Comment: thanks so much, i use your simpler option and resolve my problem thanks :)